# Luigi - Unfulfilled %s at run time

Tags: python, luigi

I am trying to learn in a very simple way how luigi works. Just as a newbie I came up with this code

```
import luigi

class class1(luigi.Task):

  def requires(self):
     return class2()

  def output(self):
    return luigi.LocalTarget('class1.txt')

 def run(self):
    print 'IN class A'


class class2(luigi.Task): 

  def requires(self):
     return []

  def output(self):
     return luigi.LocalTarget('class2.txt')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  luigi.run()
```

Running this in command prompt gives error saying

```
raise RuntimeError('Unfulfilled %s at run time: %s' % (deps, ',', '.join(missing)))
```

which is:

```
RuntimeError: Unfulfilled dependency at run time: class2__99914b932b
```

Comment: what command are you using to run it? your `run()` methods need to create the output files referenced in the `LocalTarget` in order for the dependencies to be met.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This happens because you define an output for `class2` but never create it.

Let's break it down...

When running

```
python file.py class2 --local-scheduler
```

luigi will ask:

- is the output of `class2` already on disk? NO
- check dependencies of `class2`: NONE
- execute the `run` method (by default it's and empty method `pass`)
- run method didn't return errors, so job finishes successfully.

However, when running

```
python file.py class1 --local-scheduler
```

luigi will:

- is the output of `class1` already on disk? NO
- check task dependencies: YES: `class2`
- pause to check status of class2

  - is the output of `class2` on disk? NO
  - run `class2` -> *running* -> done without errors
  - is the output of `class2` on disk? NO -> raise error

luigi never runs a task unless all of its previous dependencies are met. (i.e. their output is on the file system)

Comment: Good explanation, but what is the solution?

Comment: What happens if `class2` has no output or run function, just requires?

Comment: @KansaiRobot solution is that "class2.run()" should create the output on disk.

Comment: If `class2` is a top-level task depending on other tasks, you can simply override the `class2.complete()` method to always return True (or to check "required" tasks that they are all completed.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes because if you get the output that will never create.
ex. if the output folder create by timestamp.
timestamp change in every second so it will never be the same.
so the error could be come.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but I still haven't found it

class data_ingestion(luigi.Task):

```
def run(self):
    data = pd.read_csv('F:\Mega\MEGAsync\VS Code\winequality-red.csv', sep=';')
    data.to_csv(self.output().path, index=False)

def output(self):
    return luigi.LocalTarget('WineQuality.csv')
```

class data_prep(luigi.Task):

```
def requires(self):
    return data_ingestion()

def output(self):
    return [luigi.LocalTarget('Train.csv'), luigi.LocalTarget('Val.csv')]

def run(self):
    data = pd.read_csv('WineQuality.csv') # Lendo de um csv
    logger.info('\n Leitura rápida nos dados')
    data.head()

    column_target = 'quality' # Variável que se deseja prever
    columns_features = data.drop([column_target], axis=1)

    logger.info(f'=== Variável a ser predita: {column_target}')
    logger.info(f'=== Características disponíveis: {columns_features}')

    logger.info('Divisão do dataset em TREINO e TESTE (Validação)')
    data_train, data_val = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, stratify=data[column_target], random_state=1)
    
    logger.info(f"Salvando Train File")
    data_train.to_csv(self.output()[0].path, index=False)

    logger.info(f"Salvando Val File")
    data_val.to_csv(self.output()[1].path, index=False)
```

class training(luigi.Task):

```
def requires(self):
    return data_prep()

def output(self):
    return luigi.LocalTarget('joblibe_file') 

def run(self):

    data_train = pd.read_csv(self.input()[0].path)

    column_target = 'quality' # Variável que se deseja prever
    data_features = data_train.drop([column_target], axis=1)
    columns_features = data_features.columns.to_list()

    X_train = data_train[columns_features].values
    Y_train = data_train[column_target].values

    model = DecisionTreeRegressor() # Não implementei nenhum parâmetro pois preciso estudar certinho isso
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

    # Salvando o arquivo em um diretório de trabalho
    joblib_file = "joblib_model.pkl"
    joblib.dump(model, joblib_file)
```

class validation(luigi.Task):

```
def requires(self):
    return training()

def output(self):
    return luigi.LocalTarget('Metrics.csv')

def run(self):
    data_val = pd.read_csv(self.input()[1].path)
    
    column_target = 'quality' # Variável que se deseja prever
    data_features = data_val.drop([column_target], axis=1)
    columns_features = data_features.columns.to_list()

    X_val = data_val[columns_features].values
    Y_val = data_val[column_target].values
    
    # Importando o modelo salvo no treinamento
    joblib_model = joblib.load(self.input()[0].path) 

    y_val_predict = joblib_model.predict(X_val)
    score = joblib_model.score(X_val, Y_val)

    logger.info('=== Variáveis Preditas')
    logger.info(y_val_predict)
    logger.info('=== Acurácia')
    logger.info('{:.2f} %'.format(score))


    dict = {'Predições': [y_val_predict],
          'score': [score]} 

    df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

    logger.info(f"Salvando Em arquivo CSV para TESTE")
    df.to_csv(self.output()[0].path, index=False)
   
    # salvar várias métricas em um df e exportar
```

if **name** == '**main**':
luigi.run()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner at luigi. Thanks for pointing out this kind of errors.

Following, the previous answer I managed to solve it adding to `class2`

```
def run(self):
     _out = self.output().open('w')
     _out.write(u"Hello World!\n")
     _out.close()
     print('in class B')
```